# Are XML namespaces supposed to be effective in a template client?

Tags: jsf-2

This is no major issue, but I just want to upgrade my understanding of the specifications.

I started using **ui:composition** as the root element of my JSF pages.  When my template starts using tag libraries that are NOT in the client, I get warning messages on the rendered page.

So the Netbeans wizard gives me this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            template="./template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <h1>A simple page</h1>
    <p>
        Hi there.
    </p>
</ui:define>
```

And the rendered page shows:

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix h1 but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

So I add the **xmlns** declarations and everything is fine, but is this the way that it is supposed to work?  If not is the discontinuity with the JSF specification, XML specification, or just the Mojarra implementation, or none of the above?

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to normal Java code. If you want to use any classes, you must declare by importing their library. XML namespace is just something you need to include to declare the libraries of tags that you are going to use. It's absolutely normal that XML namespace is effective in template clients.

Besides, if you use `<ui:composition>` as your root element, you should not use normal HTML tags. Instead, you should change them to the equivalent JSF tags. If you need to use HTML tags, use `<html>` as your root element and the warning will be gone.

Comment: What's the JSF equivalent of an **h1** tag?  Does this mean that I lose all the ability to write HTML if I choose to use **ui:composition** as the root tag?

Comment: Not all HTML tags have equivalent JSF tags. JSF does not have any tags equivalent to `h1`. However, you can try something like this `<h:outputText style="font-size: 15px" value="Your text" />` to enlarge your text. And yes, you will see a lot of warnings if you use HTML tags inside `<ui:composition>` as root tag.

Answer (score 1):

> but is this the way that it is supposed to work?

Yes. JSF (and in particular Facelets) leverages plain old XML. Both the template client and the template definition are XML documents, so both need to specify their elements' namespaces in accordance with the XML specification. Put differently, the XML parser doesn't know that the document it parses will later be interpreted as a template client definition by JSF, but parses it as "just another document".